# Mega Dropdown menu seen on sitepoint: How do I show the menu on mouse click

Tags: jquery

Is there a way to display the dropdown menu shown on sitepoint by mouse click. 
http://www.sitepoint.com/blogs/2009/03/31/make-a-mega-drop-down-menu-with-jquery/

Currently, it shows the menu only on mouse hover.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add to this:

```
$("li.mega").hoverIntent(megaConfig);
```

And make it this:

```
$("li.mega").hoverIntent(megaConfig).click(addMega);
```

Depending on how you want it to behave (you can test, see which seems more natural), you may want this instead:

```
$("li.mega").hoverIntent(megaConfig).click(function() {
  $(this).toggleClass("hovering");
});
```

If you **only** want it shown on mouse click, remove the `.hoverIntent(megaConfig)` part from that last example, leaving only the `.click()` part.